# Laravel Models not found

Tags: laravel, subdirectory

I have decided to use subdirectories for my controllers so that I can manage the application better, but unfortunately I am getting an error,

```
App
    controllers
        bdm
            LeadController.php
    models
        LeadsModel.php
```

this is my LeadController.php code

```
<?php

    namespace bdm;

    use Database\Eloquent\Model; //still nothing

    class LeadController extends \BaseController 
    {

    }
```

This is my model code

```
<?php 



class LeadsModel extends Eloquent
{
    //code here
}
```

This is my Route code

```
    Route::group(
                array
                (
                    'prefix' => 'bdm' 
                ),
                function()
                {

                    Route::get('lead/index','bdm\LeadController@index');
                    Route::post('lead/get_random_lead','bdm\LeadController@getRandomLead');
                }
            );
```

The errors I am getting is:

```
{"error":{"type":"Symfony\\Component\\Debug\\Exception\\FatalErrorException","message":"Class 'bdm\\LeadsModel' not found","file":"C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\holbornasset\\crm\\app\\controllers\\bdm\\LeadController.php","line":55}}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `LeadsModel` is under global namespace. Your `LeadController` is currently under `bdm` namespace.

You have two option to call `LeadsModel` from `LeadController`

1. Add `namespace bdm` to your `LeadsModel`
2. Use backslash `\` to access LeadsModel

   ```
   \LeadsModel::find(...);
   ```

Comment: What will be the advantage/disadvantage between both options? short and concise answer. thank you

Comment: First option prevent name collision. You can have same class name but under different namespace. In large application, second is always at disadvantage because you'll have a lot of naming issue.

Comment: Now I am getting this error: Class 'bdm\\DB' not found

Comment: Got it fixed. used 'use DB'